# In a PHP file, recognize the key placed in the manifest file of an app

Tags: php

In a PHP file is it possible to read a key placed in the manifest of an Android app? In this way I would like the PHP file to process only the requests coming from a given app.

Comment: No, but you might be able to differentiate by looking at the User Agent header. (Note this is trivial to spoof though.)

Comment: If the Android app where to send this key via GET, POST or cookie to the PHP.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Same issue as with the User Agent: It's easy to send such a request, and a cookie is not more than a header either.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Since PHP is executed on the server side and the application is on the client side, one cannot just simply access a file on the client via PHP. If this were possible, it would be quite a huge security risk, since any website could then basically read arbitrary files from the client, even those that the client wishes to keep private (e. g. private SSH keys, etc.).

As Alex Howansky mentioned in his comment you could check the User Agent HTTP header comimg from the client to identify the app. That is if the app sends such a header. However, the user agent can be easily changed, most browsers offer some kind of setting or have plugins/addons that allow to change the User Agent string. Or in short: You cannot really trust the User Agent.

Comment: So there is no security. I wonder how the Google APIs make the application restrictions

Comment: @Afol Google requires Android apps to communicate with Google (Play) Services on the phone which then access the Google APIs if the requests are valid.